# How to obtain the calculation in a compact way using vector/matrix operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$N=500$.

$\vec{X}$ is a vector of length $N$. $X_{i}$ can be either $1$, $2$, or $3$.

I have a matrix $\mathbf{W}$ of size $N \times N$. It’s a symmetric matrix.

I need to perform the following

```
Sum=0;
for i=1:N
    for j=i+1:N
        if  x_i == x_j
            Sum = Sum + W_ij
        end
    end
end
```

I want to obtain `Sum`.

What is the most compact way of implementing this with linear algebra, just using vector/matrix operations?

$X_{i}$ can also be represented as a binary sequence. If $X_{i}=1$, then it can be defined as $[1~0~0]$, if $X_{i}=2$, it can be defined as $[0~ 1~ 0]$. If $X_{i}=3$, then it can be defined as $[0~ 0~ 1]$. Does it help?

Comment: Since each component of $X$ is from $\{1,2,3\}$, you can form three index sets $I,J,K$ corresponding to $x_i=1,x_j=2,x_k=3$ and then your sum can be split into three parts, e.g. $\Sigma_I=\sum w_{ii'}$ summed over $i,i'\in I$ with $i<i'$.

Comment: This is more of a programming question, and better suited for [SO] maybe. It looks like `MATLAB` code to me.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\p{\oplus}
\def\O{{\large\tt1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\xo{\LR{x\o^T-\o x^T}}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$Let $\o$ denote the all-ones vector and $M^\p$ denote the *elementwise* pseudoinverse, i.e.
$$\LR{M^\p}_{jk} = \begin{cases}
\frac{\O}{M_{jk}} \qquad {\rm if}\; M_{jk} \ne 0 \\
\;\;0\; \qquad\,{\rm otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Use this to define the pattern matrix $P_{ij}\in\{0,\o\}$
$$\eqalign{
P = \o\o^T - \xo\odot\xo^\p - I \\
}$$
where $\odot$ denotes the *elementwise* (aka Hadamard) product
and $I$ is the identity matrix.

The desired sum can be written algebraically in various ways
$$\eqalign{
\phi \;=\; \frac{P:W}2
 \;=\; \frac{\LR{\o\o^T}:\LR{P\odot W}}2
 \;=\; \frac{\trace{P^TW}}2
}$$
where the colon denotes the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
}$$
In Julia, this translates verbatim

```
u = ones(size(x)...)
P = u*u' - (x*u' - u*x') .* pinv.(x*u' - u*x') - I
ϕ = sum(P.*W) / 2
```

but it's undoubtedly faster (and more efficient) to use your original for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

If the dot product of two dissimilar binary sequences yield $0$ and similar sequences yield $1$, then I think this expression fits:

\begin{equation}
\text{Sum} = e^{T}\Big( (X X^{T}) \circ \mathbf{W} \Big)e
\end{equation}

where $A \circ B$ represents the [Schur product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) (element-wise product) of two matrices $A$ and $B$, and $e$ is an $N \times 1$ column vector whose entries are all $1$s.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Vivek Thazhathattli please explain in details. What is X here? X values themselves do not contribute to Sum. The elements in W should be added only.